# What is the format of regular expression in data-dojo-props?

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

What is the format for regular expression for `...data-dojo-props='regExp:...` I saw somwhere that this expression is fine `... data-dojo-props="regExp:'[\\w]+',...`. But this for very simple one. What if the expression is complex like

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

or

```
^(\+|00)\d{2,3}-\d{1,2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296738/correct-way-of-writing-regexp-in-data-dojo-props

Comment: @MatuDuke can you check your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not claim to be a regex expert, but I found the following to work.  The only change from what you originally posted is the comma doesn't need to be escaped.  Is this the correct validation?

```
<input 
  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
  data-dojo-props="regExp: '^[a-zA-Z]+(([\',\.-][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$'" 
  value="" name="name" id="name">
```

Comment: Its not working and generating error `Error: SyntaxError: invalid property id in data-dojo-props='regExp:'^[a-zA-Z]+(([',.-][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$'....,`

Comment: and I want to use data-dojo-props in innerHtml

Comment: Use a double quote for wrapping the xml attribute and a single quote inside the attribute value data-dojo-props="regExp:''"

Comment: Re innerHTML: I need more context.  Are you creating a custom widget?  The properties should be available on the widget class that you can then use to set on the innerHTML.